# Will a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily induce a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

> Question: We know that a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ must have a convergent sub-sequence from Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. However, will a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily induce a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$? By "induce", I mean the subset contains all the real numbers in $(x_n)$. Prove or provide counter-example.

My try: No, not necessary. To be compact the subset also has to be closed, which cannot be inferred from the question. Alternatively, to be compact, every sequence from the set has to have a convergent sub-sequence. This is not guaranteed by the question. For example, let $(x_n)=(1, 1.4, 1, 1.41, 1, 1.414, 1, 1.4149, 1, 1.41495, \cdots)$ without containing $\sqrt{2}$. Then if we form a sequence from this set by picking the even items, then it will not have a convergent sub-sequence. Is my answer right, please? Thank you!

Comment: you got the right answer there, in $\mathbb{R}$, a compact set is closed and bounded, so you have the right idea.  u just create a set that is not closed.

Comment: If $x_n\to x$ ,then {$x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...$}$\cup${$x$}is compact.

Comment: @drhab ahhh,haha.what did i wrote:P

Comment: Essential for being compact here is that the limits of subsequences are all contained in in what you call the induced set.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses!

Comment: You are right. Take, for example, the sequence of all rational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$. It's bounded, but definitely not compact=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A=\{1,1.4,1.414,1.4149,\dots\}$ is not compact, as you say, but you need to be a little careful with your justification. If you make a sequence from every second.element of this ordered set, then it *will* have a convergent subsequence--in fact, *every* subsequence of that sequence will converge to $\sqrt 2.$ However, no subsequence converges *to a point lying in* $A.$ *That* is a way we can see that $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!